# Relocating two outdoor cats from New Jersey to Florida

Tags: cats, outdoor, house-moving

Two male kittens (brothers) were born under my kitchen deck almost 5 years ago.

One allowed himself to be held for long periods of time. The other not as much, but follows me when I am outside.  They mostly stay on my deck but do travel to my rural neighborhood.  Both of them have been neutered.  They both know their names and understand a good amount of my language.

My husband and I will be committed to their safe passage and will help them establish themselves in a neighborhood much like where they are now.

So can it be done?

Comment: do they come inside your house so you can get a hold of them both at the same time? if you trap one outside you will have problems trapping the other as it will get scared.

Answer (score 4):

Feral and Outdoor are two different types of cats. One is "wild", and the other is a pet. I'd be hesitant to move feral cats, but if they are your pets, don't abandon them. I don't know you, these cats, or your daily interactions, but hopefully these help you understand the decision better.

**If you are moving any cat from it's space, you need to not only guarantee it's safe passage to the new location, but also it's well-being for the remainder of it's life.**

It  sounds like you have named these cats, and that you care about them. Do you feed them now? Do they always hang around your home? If you consider these animals your pets and want to give them a loving family, take them with you. But some preparation will be in order for the move if you are committed to these cats.

- Interact with the cats daily. Try to get them more used to your presence so *you* are home. They need to be comfortable when you are there and know that you mean safety.
- Provide food and shelter for them (if it's cold, build a heated outdoor shelter).
- Start crate training them. Entice them with treats and food and love.
- Consider taking them on car rides to get them somewhat established to the sensation. (Potty breaks will need to be considered if they've never used a litter box.)
- It's great they are neutered, but make sure they are also vaccinated and such. They could interact with new cats carrying potential diseases. Outdoor cats are especially at risk for developing health issues.

Do what you think is best for the well-being of these cats. As I tell all potential pet owners, don't commit to a pet if you can't commit to giving it the best life possible.